# Nested anchor tag Router Link not working angular 2/4

Tags: angular2-routing

Nested Link is not routing it as forwarding to parent one always, here is sample code as..  seems like angular 2/4 don't support this approach or might be something wrong with my tag, with href is it working.

```
<ul>
  <li> <a [routerLink]=['about']> </a>
   <ul>
    <li <a [routerLink]=['about/test']> </a> </li>
   </ul>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score -1):

To use anchor tags in angular 2 you need to use fragment.

Like this.

```
<a [routerLink]=['about'] fragment='test'> </a>
```

Comment: like what ? please elaborate your answer.